# Is Amtrak strict on its pet weight limits?

Tags: pets, amtrak

Amtrak allows pets in their carrier up to 20 pounds.

> Dogs and cats up to 20 pounds (combined weight of pet and carrier) are welcome on trips up to seven hours on most routes (some restrictions apply*).

Do they weigh the pets at check-in, or just eyeball? E.g. is a 23-pound dog in carrier going to be rejected?

Comment: If you don't get an answer here you might consider [Pets](https://pets.stackexchange.com) stack exchange

Comment: I don't think there are scales available on the trains or at most stations, so I can't think what they would do except eyeball.

Comment: @nate Well Ive only been to two stations

Comment: @PeterM I tried, but they deleted it because this question was still up.

Answer (score 7):

Amtrak does not weigh pets so 23 pounds should be fine.  They do have restrictions on the size for the Pet Carrier.  The maximum size for pet carriers is 19" long x 14" wide x 10.5" high. This is what they can see and would most likely flag so I would ensure that your pet carrier is within the max limits.

Comment: Thanks! 23 lbs was just an example - my dog is well over that, but I was just curious.

Comment: Yes, additionally I have traveled Amtrak many times over the last 20 years and both never seen a pet weighed or even seen the equipment for weighing a pet.  I also just traveled with a pet on an airline in May and they didn't weight the pet.  This may have been because the plane was very empty.